# Load and display WebM's & Gif's from a URL to an ImageView with Volley or Picasso

Tags: android, image, android-volley, picasso

I'm trying to build an app which displays .jpg, .png, .webm and .gif (also animated) in a ListView from a URL. I receive the URL via a JSON request. I managed to receive the JSON response and the Image/WebM/Gif URL via Volley and tried to display it via ImageLoader in a NetworkImageView. JPG and PNG work fine but WebM and Gif wont playback. WebM wont even show a frame as Gif does (first frame only). Then I tried it with Picasso and a normal ImageView. Same results. JPG and PNG work but the other two wont. Does anybody have an idea how I can load WebM and Gif form a URL to a ImageView or NetworkImageView which later will be inside a ListView?

I thought about using WebView but as I dont have much experience with it I don't really know if it's good for the performance to have multiple WebViews in a ListView.

I hope somebody has an idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22862991/2111834), you can use Glide, thought I'm not sure WebM will also work. See if it meets your criteria :)

Comment: Have you tried "Ion"? It loads Images and Gifs without problem (both in ImageView). Though I'm looking for a solution to also loads .webm files / gifv's

Answer (score 0):

For the animated gif images, I would recommend the [android-gif-drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable) library. The included `GifImageView` is behaving like a normal `ImageView` but supports animated gifs.

To display the webm video a [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) should work.

Comment: I tried using GifImageView it doesn't change anythign. Could it be that Picasso doesn't actually load the Gif? So the GifImageView can't playback?

Comment: How do you pass the gif from Picasso to GifImageView?

Comment: I just load the gif URL. Same as if it would be a JPG or PNG.